# How to incorporate Environments with JClouds-Chef API?

Tags: java, chef-infra, roles, environment, jclouds

I am using [JClouds-Chef](http://jclouds.apache.org/guides/chef/) to:

1. Bootstrap a newly-provisioned Linux VM; and *then*
2. Run the chef-client on that node to configure it

It's important to note that all I'm currently configuring Chef with is a role (that's all it needs; everything else is set up on the Chef server for me):

```
public class ChefClient {
    public configure() {
        String vmIp = "myapp01.example.com";
        String vmSshUsername = "myuser";
        String vmSshPassword = "12345";

        String endpoint = "https://mychefserver.example.com";
        String client = "myuser";
        String validator = "chef-validator";
        String clientCredential = Files.toString(new File("C:\\Users\\myuser\\sandbox\\chef\\myuser.pem"), Charsets.UTF_8);
        String validatorCredential = Files.toString(new File("C:\\Users\\myuser\\sandbox\\chef\\chef-validator.pem"), Charsets.UTF_8);

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ChefProperties.CHEF_VALIDATOR_NAME, validator);
        props.put(ChefProperties.CHEF_VALIDATOR_CREDENTIAL, validatorCredential);
        props.put(Constants.PROPERTY_RELAX_HOSTNAME, "true");
        props.put(Constants.PROPERTY_TRUST_ALL_CERTS, "true");

        ChefContext ctx = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("chef")
            .endpoint(endpoint)
            .credentials(client, clientCredential)
            .overrides(props)
            .modules(ImmutableSet.of(new SshjSshClientModule())) //
            .buildView(ChefContext.class);
        ChefService chef = ctx.getChefService();

        List<String> runlist = new RunListBuilder().addRole("platformcontrol_dev").build();

        ArrayList<String> runList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String item : runlist) {
            runList2.add(item);
        }

        BootstrapConfig bootstrapConfig = BootstrapConfig.builder().runList(runList2).build();

        chef.updateBootstrapConfigForGroup("jclouds-chef", bootstrapConfig);

        Statement bootstrap = chef.createBootstrapScriptForGroup("jclouds-chef");

        SshClient.Factory sshFactory = ctx.unwrap().utils()
            .injector().getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<SshClient.Factory>() {}));

        SshClient ssh = sshFactory.create(HostAndPort.fromParts(vmIp, 22),
            LoginCredentials.builder().user(vmSshUsername).password(vmSshPassword).build());

        ssh.connect();

        try {
            StringBuilder rawScript = new StringBuilder();

            Map<String, String> resolvedFunctions = ScriptBuilder.resolveFunctionDependenciesForStatements(
                new HashMap<String, String>(), ImmutableSet.of(bootstrap), OsFamily.UNIX);

            ScriptBuilder.writeFunctions(resolvedFunctions, OsFamily.UNIX, rawScript);
            rawScript.append(bootstrap.render(OsFamily.UNIX));

            ssh.put("/tmp/chef-bootstrap.sh", rawScript.toString());
            ExecResponse result = ssh.exec("bash /tmp/chef-bootstrap.sh");
        } catch(Throwable t) {
            println "Exception: " + t.message
        } finally {
            ssh.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Our in-house "Chef" (our devops guy) now wants to add the concept of Chef "[environments](http://docs.getchef.com/essentials_environments.html)" to all our recipes in addition to the existing roles. This is so that we can specify environment-specific roles for each node. My question: does the JClouds-Chef API handle environments? If so, how might I modify the code to incorporate environment-specific roles?

Is it just as simple as:

```
BootstrapConfig bootstrapConfig = BootstrapConfig.builder()
    .environment("name-of-env-here?").runList(runList2).build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is that simple. That will tell the bootstrap script to register the node in the specified environment.

Take into account, though, that the environment **must already exist** in the Chef Server. If you want to create nodes in new environments, you can also create them programmatically as follows:

```java
ChefApi api = ctx.unwrapApi(ChefApi.class);
if (api.getEnvironment("environment-name") == null) {
    Environment env = Environment.builder()
        .name("environment-name")
        .description("Some description")
        .build();
    api.createEnvironment(env);
}
```